# How to efficiently change value for a certain key in object that has recursion in JS/TS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, object, recursion

I have a tree component that accepts the following data structure

```
type TreeNode = {
  id: string,
  parentId: string,
  renderer: () => React.ReactNode,
  expanded: boolean,
  children?: Array<TreeNode>,
}
```

And I want to implement the `Expand All / Collapse All` functionality which is technically changing the `expanded` to `true/false` for all TreeNodes for that tree.

When I had `label: string` instead of `renderer: function`, I used the following method, which seems to be perfect.

```
function updateAllNodes(rootNode, newExpanded) {
    return JSON.parse(
        JSON.stringify(rootNode)
            .replaceAll(
                `"expanded": ${!newExpanded}`, 
                `"expanded": ${newExpanded}`
            )
    );
}
```

But as long as we have a renderer function for nodes, I can no longer use this methodology.

What is the best solution for this?

Comment: Why don't you use recurring function?

Comment: What's not working with your react function?

Comment: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify()) will remove all functions

Comment: Absolutely do not use string replacement on JSON to update your data!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say we have `mytree` -

```js
const mytree =
  { id: 1, active: false, children: [
      { id: 11, active: true, children: [
          { id: 111, active: false },
          { id: 112, active: true }
        ]
      },
      { id: 12, active: false },
      { id: 13, active: true, children: [
          { id: 131, active: false }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

You can **immutably update** using a recursive function `recUpdate` -

```js
const recUpdate = (t, f) =>
  ({ ...t, children: t?.children?.map(c => recUpdate(c, f)), ...f(t) })
```

Our higher-order function can be specialized to write `activate` and `deactivate` -

```js
const activate = t =>
  recUpdate(t, _ => ({ active: true }))

const deactivate = t =>
  recUpdate(t, _ => ({ active: false }))
```

Calling `activate` will produce a new tree where all `active = true` -

```js
console.log(activate(mytree))
```

```js
{ id: 1, active: true, children: [
    { id: 11, active: true, children: [
        { id: 111, active: true },
        { id: 112, active: true }
      ]
    },
    { id: 12, active: true },
    { id: 13, active: true, children: [
        { id: 131, active: true }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Calling `deactivate` will produce a new tree where all `active = false` -

```js
console.log(deactivate(mytree))
```

```js
{ id: 1, active: false, children: [
    { id: 11, active: false, children: [
        { id: 111, active: false },
        { id: 112, active: false }
      ]
    },
    { id: 12, active: false },
    { id: 13, active: false, children: [
        { id: 131, active: false }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

`mytree` is not mutated -

```js
console.log(mytree)
```

```js
{ id: 1, active: false, children: [
    { id: 11, active: true, children: [
        { id: 111, active: false },
        { id: 112, active: true }
      ]
    },
    { id: 12, active: false },
    { id: 13, active: true, children: [
        { id: 131, active: false }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Expand the snippet below to verify the result in your browser -

```js
const recUpdate = (t, f) =>
  ({ ...t, children: t?.children?.map(c => recUpdate(c, f)), ...f(t) })

const activate = t =>
  recUpdate(t, _ => ({ active: true }))

const deactivate = t =>
  recUpdate(t, _ => ({ active: false }))

const mytree =
  { id: 1, active: false, children: [
      { id: 11, active: true, children: [
          { id: 111, active: false },
          { id: 112, active: true }
        ]
      },
      { id: 12, active: false },
      { id: 13, active: true, children: [
          { id: 131, active: false }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }

console.log(JSON.stringify(activate(mytree)))
console.log(JSON.stringify(deactivate(mytree)))
console.log(JSON.stringify(mytree))
```